# LightDM login Background Sync with Nitrogen

Tags: lightdm, openbox

I use nitrogen to control my background in openbox.

Is there a way to sync this with LightDM login so that I have the same background on the log in screen as on openbox?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my computer (Ubuntu 14.10)
Run it when you change the nitrogen background.
**Note: Do NOT run this code as root; it will ask for root when nessarary!**

`#! /bin/bash`

`# backgroundsync.sh -- Sync background between nitrogen and lightdm`

```
IMAGE=`cat ~/.config/nitrogen/* | grep "file" | cut -d "=" -f2 | head -n 1`
```

`sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash << END
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'false'
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background '$IMAGE'
END`